# increment SQL field manually

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to create a SAP UDO for product registrations. The UDO automatically creates two required fields "docentry" and "code." docentry auto-increments, code does not. I don't have accessing to the underlying database structure to fix that, but I can attach a query to the code field.

When a record is created, can I setup a query that would increment based on the previous row's value for code? I'm not looking for anything useful out of this field, but we will need to both batch import .csv files on a regular basis and also take direct submissions from our site, so I'm just looking for the easiest way to make it work.

Thank you.

EDIT from OP comment:

> *"We're using SQL server 2008 R2, and 'docentry' is the unique PK."*

Comment: Do you just need a unique key in docentry or are you forced to use ascending numerical keys for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name_here SET code = code + 1 WHERE ? = ??
```

Replace the `?` with unique identifier column name and `??` with it's value for row you are working with.

After your comment:
Let's say you have previous row `code` value stored in $1 and actual row `id` in $2. Then:

```
UPDATE registrations SET code = $1 + 1 WHERE id = $2
```

After your second comment:

```
UPDATE registrations SET code = (SELECT MAX(code) FROM registrations) + 1 WHERE docentry = `new_row_docentry_value`
```

Comment: UPDATE registrations SET code = code + 1 WHERE (code = previous row's value of code. How do I call this out?) Or am i thinking about this wrong?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but I can still improve it, to be complete SQL, if you will tell me: 1. Which DBMS are you using? 2. What is the unique identifier column name in this table? I'll be back after 4 hours.

Comment: We're using SQl server 2008 R2, and 'docentry' is the unique PK.